# Working from a USB

Tags: privacy, account-security, usb, data-recovery, programming

I have a Mac for my work laptop and I would like to work on my xCode project, I can't work on the laptop directly and save the file to computer due to fears that it could one day be recovered & be property of the company, but would it be possible to work on my xCode project through a USB on my work computer without any files being recovered somehow?

Comment: The answer below is better than what I can offer. Other than, have you considered just getting a waiver for your application?  The last company I worked for built it into our contract that anything we wrote they owned. So every time I built something new I went through a request process and they released ownership to me.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, data will be stored in the RAM for you to interact with. At some point data from the RAM might be stored to swap and that is on you hard drive. So I guess you cannot develop on your work computer without data being stored on its hard drive.

That being said, I don't know Xcode, but it might store files (for instance temp files) on your hard drive anyway. You might be able to change that in the settings, though.

Another approach would be to delete everything (swap and files) and thoroughly wipe free space (with a tool such as CCleaner) before giving back the computer, hence ensuring they cannot carve it.

Beware that in some countries, if they can prove you used work properties to develop your program (like thanks to this post), they could claim it anyway.